# Error: spawn cucumber-json-formatter ENOENT (linux)

Tags: linux, cypress, enoent

i need your help for this :

```
An error was thrown in your plugins file while executing the handler for the after:run event.

The error we received was:

Error: spawn cucumber-json-formatter ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when upgraded to the last version of the **@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor** because it was missing the [cucumber-json-formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter) that according to [the documentation](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/json-report.md#json-reports) must be configured. Once I added, the issue gone.

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks so much for helping out here! It took me hours to find a solution.

Comment: So, now that fails in my Azure Pipeline. Any idea how I would install that on their machine?

Comment: I only get this error AFTER installing and configuring the cucumber-json-formatter!